# Limits on httpd Include wildcard?

Tags: linux, apache, configuration, filesystems

Without going into too much detail, I have a 3rd party service that produces httpd configuration files.

There maybe occurrences where it produces thousands of files.

If I do a `Include conf/extra/mydir/*.conf` is there a limit to the number of files that can be pulled in via this directive?

Comment: IS this related to programming?

Comment: Apache config = Devops.

Comment: Sorry, it is not. Apache configuration as well as other server configuration issues are discussed on Serverfault.